# Integrate my own authentication into Blazor 8 SSR + WebAssembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm currently hitting a wall trying to integrate the jwt authentication used in my company into the new Blazor template (SSR + Web Assembly). The problem I'm having is for Web Assembly pages (Client project) with authorize attributes, I get the browser awful 401 error, instead of get redirected to the Login page in the server project.

I know this is probably uncharted territory. Any ide what's missing?

Below is the Routes configuration:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client.IClientMarker).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

RedirectToLogin is failing to redirect to my login page, *OnInitialized* is never executed.

*RedirectToLogin.cs:*

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Auth/Login");
}
```

Program.cs:

```
    ...
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config["Jwt:Key"]!)),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = config["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true
        };
    });

...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseAntiforgery();
...
```

[image]

Comment: Which render mode you have used for this blazor aplication?

Comment: @BrandoZhang  Web Assembly